# Retrieving JSON from server using Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to create a drop-down list using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) and JSON data from a server. I attempted to follow their example and it works but I am having a hard time completing it.

I use the code below to get the data from the database, I can print it out to the console, but I can't get the data to show as a drop-down

```
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "DBHandler.php?k=",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {  
            console.log(params.term);
            return {                     
                search: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
            // scrolling can be used
            console.log(data)
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.items
                //pagination: {
                    //more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                //}
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 3
});
```

My HTML:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

My PHP:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
echo json_encode(array_unique($results));
```

console.log(data) output:

```
Zuber, W. P., Mrs.,Zoellner String Quartet,Zeta Chi,YWCA,Yonge, H. M.,YMCA Friendship Council,YMCA,Yellow Fever,yearbooks,Yarbrough, Reed, Mrs.,Yancey, William L.,Yale University,Yale,Wynne, W. W.,Wynne, Andrew Jackson "Jack",writing,Wright, T. P. (Thomas Parks),Wright, Homer,Wright, G. H.,Wright & Co.,wrestling,Worms Orchestra,World War I,World War 1,World Series,World Fellowship Campaign,Wooten, B. A. (Benjamin Allen),Woodmen's Circle,Woodmen of the World,Woodall, A. M. (Aaron Montgomery),Wood, Leonard, 1860-1927,Wood, Clement, 1888-1950,Wood, C. P.,wood,women,Woman's Missionary Society,Wolcott, Edward Oliver, 1848-1905,Wofford College,Wisconsin,Wirt Society student organizations,Wirt Society,Wirt Literary Society,Winston, Margaret,Winston, E. T.,Windham,
```

So my question is how do I get the data.items to populate the `<select></select>` tags?

Comment: did you tried to loop `data.items` and do something along lines `$.append` to your `select` dropdown?

Comment: I tired that. Let me try again.

Comment: my first comment was wrong ,, I see in docs that if you use ajax from `select2` than this line `results: data.items,` should render results for you,, can you paste your json data please, just excerpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Kresimir Pendic stated, the problem was with my `JSON` string. It was formatted incorrectly.

> This code only retrieved one column. It then attempted to convert that data into `JSON`.
>  **Totally wrong**

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
echo json_encode(array_unique($results));
```

> **To achieve the correct structure**, I had to create `outputArray`. I then used a for loop to go through each value returned in `result`. I stored each value into `outputArray` by creating a new `Array` with a structure of `'id' => $counter, 'text' => $result[0]`. Each new `Array` created was pushed into `outputArray`. Finally, I used `json_encode($outputArray)` on the `outputArray` and `echo`ed the results.

```
$outputArray = array();       
for($i = 0; $result = $stmt->fetch(); $i++)
{
    $counter = $i + 1;
    array_push($outputArray, array('id' => $counter, 'text' => $result[0]));  
}        
$json = json_encode($outputArray);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to format your JSON in diff way.. I'll paste one that needs to have the struct in this way,, have child node `items` with array of values with atleast `id` and `name` ( for your dropdown to fill values and names for values to show when dropdown opens)

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1225212",
      "name": "Name 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "6546542",
      "name": "Name 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

hope that helps, good luck,, I know that select2 can be pain in the axx :)

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks!